# Cant authenticate to Doubleclick bid manager Api using a service account

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client, double-click

i write some code to connect with google api `Doubleclick bid manager`

I download client_secrets.json at `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?` then run some code like

```
require 'google/apis/doubleclickbidmanager_v1'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
service = Google::Apis::DoubleclickbidmanagerV1::DoubleClickBidManagerService.new
service.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager'])
service.download_line_items
```

it response some errors like:

> Sending HTTP post https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems?
>       403
>       #https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems == 403 (354 bytes) 1091ms>
>       Caught error unauthorizedApiAccess: You are not authorized to use DoubleClick Bid Manager API. Please contact dbm-support@google.com.
>       Error - #
>
> Google::Apis::ClientError: unauthorizedApiAccess: You are not authorized to use DoubleClick Bid Manager API. Please contact dbm-support@google.com.
>   And when i run api at `https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer`, it return `"You are not authorized to use DoubleClick Bid Manager API. Please contact dbm-support@google.com."` too
>   Some one know this errors, plz check and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your application requests private data, the request must be authorized by an authenticated user who has access to that data.  Every request your application sends to the Google DoubleClick Bid Manager API must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google.

This is what the error means by

> "You are not authorized to use DoubleClick Bid Manager API.

Make sure that you include the following scope when requesting authentication of the user.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager

More info can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/how-tos/authorizing) and there is documentation here on how to get it working with [ruby](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/aaa_oauth) you will need to alter the example there for your api as this is for calendar.

Note about service accounts.

Service accounts must be pre-authorized in order to work.  In the case of Google drive you can take the service account email address and share a folder on your google drive with it.  Basically you share data with the service account granting it access to the data.  Not all google apis support service account authentication.   Youtube api, Doubleclick, and blogger I think addsence or adWords as well, are a few that do not support service account authentication as there is no way to share the data with a user without them responding to the share request.

Comment: i following the last guide `Service accounts`
```
scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager'
service = Google::Apis::DoubleclickbidmanagerV1::DoubleClickBidManagerService.new
service.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)

service.download_line_items
```
but its still same error
PS: i download client_secrets.json from `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials`

Comment: The double click api does not support service account authentication you will need to use oauth2 authentication.  As stated here https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/how-tos/authorizing

Comment: @DalmTo: thank you for your information. So there is no way to use DBM API with server to server flow? I need to authenticate and call the Google API directly. There is no end user in this case :(

Comment: Well if you want to access someones data you are going to have to authenticate to the user who owns the data so there is an end user.

Comment: @DalmTo: you're right. Sorry for my bad explanation. What I'm trying to do is accessing my data or another user (I have his google username and password) 's data. And there is no web feature for that. Just make a call from my server directly to google API. I wonder if it is possible? Thanks.

Comment: You still need to use Oauth2.  You cant use a service account.   Just save the refresh token and use it to access the api as needed

Comment: Hi @DalmTo, i try to Oauth2 with end user with flow at `https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/how-tos/authorizing`  guide, then I have `access token`, then I use this token to request with gem `google-api-client` but it always return `You are not authorized to use DoubleClick Bid Manager API`
Then I use `Google API explorer` and authen with Oauth2, but it return `You are not authorized to use DoubleClick Bid Manager API` too
I think  my account be crazy T.T . Please help me and save my life

Comment: I am getting an empty response using a service account. Also according to the documentation. It is possible to use a service account. I don't why it's been said here by many that you cannot?
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
@DaImTo Also as it seems from that link. The service account and oauth2 aren't two separate things. You could use a service account with oauth2

Comment: Where exactly on that page does it state that it works with double bid?   Zero response means that your service account has no data.   Last I checked there was no way to share the data with a service account.    If you do manage to do that please let us know

Comment: The documentation still lists only Oauth2 for authentication methods https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/how-tos/authorizing so I think it's safe to say service accounts are still not supported